# How to start the associated program when selecting more than one files?

Tags: file, associations

I have set .jpg file associated to my own program. I want to add the context menu to .jpg files, so I set the entry of HKCR.jpg\shell\open\command to "myProg.exe %1". After associating, there will be an item on the top of the context menu saying "Open image with myprog". This works right when I select a single .jpg file, but when I selected more than one file and click the top item of the context menu, nothing happended. How can I solve the problem?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Each selected file will be sent to a new instance of your application. Your application should check if a previous version exists, or not. If a previous instance exists, it should sent its parameters to it (e.g. using Windows Messages) and then terminate.

Another approach is to use DDE ([Dynamic Data Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648711(VS.85).aspx)), an old method used by Shell to send all files to one instance of your program.

Comment: But when I select more than one files, no instance of my program was started at all.

Comment: Use double quotes around the %1.

Comment: I used double quotes,like this:
"C:\\myProg.exe" "%1"

What is wired is that it worked well when one file selected but failed when mutiple files selected. I don't know why.

Comment: When mutiple files are selected, is there an instance which does not receive the parameters, or there is no instance of your application at all?

Comment: When mutiple files are selected, there is no instance of my application at all.

Answer (score 0):

You might need double quotes around the "%1".

Read this article for much more detailed information about how all this works.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776883.aspx

Also, this blog entry talks about what you need to do specifically for multi-select command execution: http://blogs.msdn.com/pix/archive/2006/06/30/652889.aspx